# Easiest way to run a Python script (that access the internet) once a day?

Tags: python

I wrote a simple script that parses some stuff off the web and emails it to me. Very simple. But I'm starting to realize that implementing this is going to be far more difficult that it really should be.

All I really want to do is run this script once a day.

I have explored using Google App Engine, but it doesn't like smtplib using ssl to login to my gmail to send an email.

I am considering using Heroku, but that just seems like a lot of work for something so simple.

I tried using my raspberry pi, but I'm not sure the script is still running when I exit ssh. I looked into running the scrip on a cron job, but I'm not sure thats an elegant solution.

I looked into running an [applescript](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-4082) from my calendar, but I'm not sure what happens if my computer is closed and/or offline.

My question is: Is there a simple, elegant, easy solution here?

Comment: use you raspberry pi and use crontab

Comment: GAE doesn't like  smptplib ? Care to explain in what sense ?

Comment: Heroku would be the easiest thing. The free [scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler) can be setup to run your script once a day and you can use [sendgrid](https://addons.heroku.com/sendgrid) for free to send yourself emails.

Comment: 1. Use the Raspi and tmux to make sure the process keeps running when you leave the ssh session. 2. You can use GAE to send emails from the app account: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/ I believe you get 100 free emails/24 hour period

Comment: GAE doesn't like starttls: `server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587) #port 465 or 587
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()` And I didn't want to rewrite my app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the script from your session (./script.py or python script.py) than it stops running when you disconnect. If you want to run the script this way for whatever reason, I would recommend using tmux .

If you're using Raspian or another Debian based distro for your Pi:

```
$ apt-get install tmux
$ tmux
# disconnect from your tmux session with pressing CTRL+B and (after that) D
# to reattach to your session later, use
$ tmux attach
```

I would recommend using cron. Just add a file like this in `/etc/cron.d/`, if you want to run it at a specific time (e.g. every day at 1am), like so:

```
$ echo "0 1 * * * python /path/to/your/script.py > /dev/null 2>&1" > /etc/cron.d/script-runner
# and don't forget to make it executable
$ chmod +x /etc/cron.d/script-runner
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) has a nice explanation of the format (and also of shortcuts like @hourly and @daily).

If you don't care when exactly it runs, you can just put your script into `/etc/cron.daily/`. Don't forget a `chmod +x` to make it executable.

If you don't want to run it on one of your machines, you can also get a shell on one of [uberspaces](https://uberspace.de) servers. You can pay whatever you wan't (minimum 1 Eur/month) and you get a shell on a linux box with 10GB storage (the first month is free for testing, cancelation happens automatically when you don't pay, no strings attached). I'm sure there are a lot of other services like that, I just mention it, because it's a cheap one with nice support. Also you get a domain (..uberspace.de) and can send mail from the server (e.g. with `mail`). So no need to use a gmail account.

Edit: Overread the "python" part. Changed everything to .py. Either use `#!/usr/bin/env python3` (or 2.7) in your script or start the script via `python scriptname.py`.

Comment: thanks for this. cron probably looks easiest. I'm curious -- what would happen if I scheduled a cron job through my laptop and it was closed or offline? Would the job run as soon as I opened it?

Comment: Come to think of it, I think my email implementation is a bit of a hack. I wouldn't expect to have to write out my gmail password in plain text in my code... How would this work to send email directly from the server?

Comment: On the commandline (or in a bash script) you can just use mail: `mail -s <subject> <emailaddress>` and than type the text. To finish and send the mail, type a `.` in a new line. To use it in a script you can use: `mail -s <subject> <emailaddress> < "Text"`

Comment: With python just take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email-examples.html) (or the corresponding 2.7 version). Be aware though, that you can't send mail from a dial-up connection, since those will be blacklisted by almost any other mailserver.